# In Ruby testing, is there a way to check several fields but only raise exception afterwards covering all mismatches

Tags: ruby

For example, say I am comparing many values via assertions, it might fail on the first, but also have an issue with some others.  Rather than fixing/re-running per issue, it would seem to be handier to check all values and then if any mismatch, raise an assertion failure at the end highlighting all mismatches.

Then again, perhaps I am attacking this problem in the wrong way...

Hope that makes sense - thanks in advance for all advice.

For example:

```
it 'expensive to run and does not stop on the first failure' do
  aggregate_failures do
    expect(1).to eq 2
    expect(2).to eq 3
    expect(3).to eq 4
    expect(4).to eq 5
    expect(5).to eq 6
  end
end
```

Comment: some examples would be good...

Comment: What's the point of your edit? Didn't my post answer your question? This exact syntax will work in rspec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using RSpec, it has that ability in the current version (v3 at the moment).

```
it 'does not stop on the first failure' do
  aggregate_failures do
    expect(1).to eq 2
    expect(2).to eq 3
  end
end
```

Comment: Many Thanks for this - my edit was for those who wanted an example.  Would love a pure ruby solution. Annoying getting gems through our work firewall :(

Comment: @ChrisKimpton: Not sure what you mean. Rspec is "pure ruby". If you can't install gems, then you're restricted to reinventing wheels until the end of time. In which case, why don't you just go and implement this for your testing framework, which you presumably have written already (out of necessity)? :)

Comment: Sorry, wasn't very clear - we are using JRuby, via the "complete" jar which includes some gems. We can get additional gems, its just not a standard workflow. Currently using test-unit

Answer (score 1):

You should generally have one assertion per example. The point of that is what you pointed out, which is so that it doesn't skip any assertions, and shows all failures at the end.

Comment: This is not always practical. Sometimes setup is expensive.

Comment: Reliability should not be sacrificed for the convenience of speed

Comment: In Rspec you can have both :)